# Selection of RC values based on application - How?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ground, ethernet, capacitance, layout

Please see the below connections:

[image]

I have seen long back another board and chassis ground connection with an RC with a different set of RC values.

I read that the capacitor is there to build a low-impedance path for high frequencies.
So it´s on the application what frequencies I want to focus on and what impedance I want at these frequencies

I need to calculate based on the Xc = 1/(2pifC) formula, right? In that case, what should the frequency I need to be focusing on 100/1000BASE-TX ethernet and USB 2.0/3.0? Any idea on this?

Also, any Idea on the purpose and the value of the resistor?

Comment: It depends what EMI, EMC and surge tests you want to pass. Where do you intend to sell your device? Also the 1 Mohm resistor is problematic, can it handle 1500 VAC over it and not even sure about if it fails leakage test simply by being there. And yes there is a huge difference between 100M and 1000M Ethernet, and huge difference between USB 2 and 3, in fact it depends on if you mean Type-C connector or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Somethings are not very clear. Why should the 1Mohm handle 1500AC? Also, what is a leakage test?

Comment: Ethernet is a galvanically isolated interface that is required to withstand 1500 VAC or about 2200 VDC of potential difference. Also static electricity discharges are many kilovolts and the capacitor must handle the energy so that it is not charged to more than 1 or 2 kilovolts. So in worst case, during high potential safety tests and ESD tests that need to be done before you can sell your product, there will be 1500 VAC or about 2200 peak voltage over the resistor and capacitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The capacitor is there to be a low impedance or short circuit to high frequency AC and the resistor is there to weakly keep both ends of the capacitor at the same DC potential.

But it's not really that simple, because while the capacitor may be used as AC ground return path for signals, it's also for handling discharges of static electricity, which are not really frequencies you can calculate with, but high speed bursts or spikes of energy.

The capacitor voltage and capacitance are selected so that it can handle a specific level of standard discharge test in a way that the charge transferred by a discharge event will be handled by the capacitance so that the voltage of the capacitor does not exceed the voltage it is rated to handle.

As the capacitor has capacitance, any charge or spark cannot make the voltage jump immediately as the voltage depends on how much charge was transferred and capacitance, and the voltage rise speed is determined by the current and capacitance.

That's why the capacitor is there, to limit the rate of voltage changes between two equipment.

The resistor is drawn there to discharge the capacitor in order to equalize potentials of the two devices after they have been connected together.

Now, the calculations are tricky as there are no simple ways of determining them.

Sometimes there are safety rules and electrical codes how a device must be built or should not be built in order to pass safety and other tests made them to ensure they are safe and fulfill the required electrical codes for them.

In some cases simply because you are building a standard interface like Ethernet or USB defines how connector chassis should be connected to digital ground, or how they should not.

In EMC tests they are tested that they do not radiate or conduct too much electrical interference out of them, like from the Ethernet or USB cables if they are acting as antennas when connected to the device.

That's already a third thing to balance and what's best from e.g. safety point of view may not be best from EMC compatibility view and yet the device must still fulfill requirements of Ethernet or USB to pass standard compliance from the signal integrity point of view.

In many cases, for Ethernet, the resistor would be absent. But it again depends how the system ground connects to e.g. metal chassis or mains earth so in some cases the capacitor is omitted too.

For USB it also depends. USB2 just requires best practices, but Type-C requires receptacle shell to be connected to PCB ground plane, so if that is a tested thing to pass official USB compliance testing, that's how it must be then.

Usually when designing a device, chip manufacturer examples give good suggestions what you should do based on which interface is in question, and they usually have investigated different options from different aspects and have an approximately average solution how it should be done, and it may depend on the device role, like is your product an USB host, an USB device, or both if it's an USB OTG port.